# PHP JSON decode Amazon SNS

Tags: php, json, amazon-sns

I'm having issues decoding certain Amazon SNS notifications using PHP's `json_decode` (5.3.10-1ubuntu3.5) and have not yet been able to figure out why despite the json being marked as valid using jsonlint.com.  Can someone point me in the correct direction?  Here are two examples:

```
{
  "Type" : "Notification",
  "MessageId" : "8q787fm3-f7fe-5sf4-863e-331bre627f24",
  "TopicArn" : "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:1234567890:ses-bounces-topic",
  "Message" : "{\"notificationType\":\"Bounce\",\"bounce\":{\"reportingMTA\":\"dns; a193-136.smtp-out.amazonses.com\",\"bounceType\":\"Transient\",\"bouncedRecipients\":[{\"emailAddress\":\"email@example.com\",\"status\":\"5.0.0\",\"diagnosticCode\":\"smtp; 5.3.0 - Other mail system problem 571-'5.7.1 Message contains spam or virus or sender is blocked : 17624:1603463706|734463C' (delivery attempts: 0)\",\"action\":\"failed\"}],\"bounceSubType\":\"General\",\"timestamp\":\"2013-03-11T22:15:21.000Z\",\"feedbackId\":\"0000013d5b854265-18f16a12-8a99-11e2-aa8d-81a75f1af476-000000\"},\"mail\":{\"timestamp\":\"2013-03-11T22:14:51.000Z\",\"source\":\"otheremail@example.com\",\"messageId\":\"0000013d5b853e2a-820173e1-095e-4h91-9c91-03876f970534-000000\",\"destination\":[\"email@example.com\"]}}",
  "Timestamp" : "2013-03-11T22:14:52.935Z",
  "SignatureVersion" : "1",
  "Signature" : "bY5gjFMgrVnK+4Qw867qHR0cLDXlgZmYb6EdiDAd4hNHMDab4J5MdldldEQwkSFslkdkDsdowlsKAdQvZ9HZwSmEcTRpwgg3Fpp5R/efVnTdUVfJkmBcnhijhWHpxSdEqN9m5vgPhg=",
  "SigningCertURL" : "https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-f3ecfb7224c72n3fe7bp5KDMMX6de32f.pem",
  "UnsubscribeURL" : "https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:1234567890:ses-bounces-topic:73m9983aa-0f4b-4r87-a5d7-d43pb99c91af"
}
```

And

```
{
  "Type" : "Notification",
  "MessageId" : "3c91t096-h331-5dm1-9u22-8822c3cdb7e8",
  "TopicArn" : "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:1234567890:ses-bounces-topic",
  "Message" : "{\"notificationType\":\"Bounce\",\"bounce\":{\"reportingMTA\":\"dsn; aws-ses-mta-svc-iad-1d-i-ccb81arf.us-east-1.amazon.com\",\"bounceType\":\"Permanent\",\"bouncedRecipients\":[{\"emailAddress\":\"email@example.com\",\"status\":\"5.1.1\",\"diagnosticCode\":\"smtp; 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try\\\\n550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or\\\\n550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at\\\\n550 5.1.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=6596 ht9si5931660qab.18 - gsmtp\",\"action\":\"failed\"}],\"bounceSubType\":\"General\",\"timestamp\":\"2013-03-08T16:15:40.000Z\",\"feedbackId\":\"0000015m4ac15133-4b74a3sf-890b-11e2-bf3f-53yadf2149d9-000000\"},\"mail\":{\"timestamp\":\"2013-03-08T16:15:39.000Z\",\"source\":\"otheremail@example.com\",\"messageId\":\"0000017d44c94bnf-a333d68b-8bed-4a2b-bdbf-4156zb5cdd9f-000000\",\"destination\":[\"example@sample.com\"]}}",
  "Timestamp" : "2013-03-08T16:15:40.472Z",
  "SignatureVersion" : "1",
  "Signature" : "pYxerRQVHo0kgbLh4a/nri8Rveqdlb/CbPuXEkdCaBt7ulJ5G5gU6TYaUM94iFnCTBC9+5dLZRvydIsemFCiUQUArsh30tcgzBbb2rb7cuZoi09T4bYByN9FY=",
  "SigningCertURL" : "https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-f3mcfb7224c7235fe7bb5f79f96dd52p.pem",
  "UnsubscribeURL" : "https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:1234567890:ses-bounces-topic:7p37c3za-0h4b-4j87-a5i7-d42cb90c9maf"
}
```

I see that jsonlint.com says it's valid JSON I just can't figure out why when I pass the contents of the RAW post to `json_decode` it's returning null.  For the first level of JSON I'm using:

```
$result = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
if (!empty($result)) { }
```

I should add per E_ERROR's question I definitely have `json_decode` as some/most of the notifications are parsed correctly.  I'm just getting a subset that for some reason aren't.

UPDATE: It's been a while so my head is not in this code anymore but to answer Hasan's question.  Here is the working code and my comment about it.

```
// json_decode does not like single quotes in the response so strip them here
$notification = str_replace("'", '', $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
$result = json_decode($notification);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What issue are you having?

Comment: Does function json_decode() exist? Check it.

Comment: I use this class (not only in Yii projects) for such cases when json is not enabled https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.13/framework/web/helpers/CJSON.php

Comment: What are the "issues" you are having?  Do you get any errors?  What happens when you tried `json_decode`?

Comment: Also try json_last_error() to debug

Comment: I tried the 2nd one with `json_decode` and it worked fine.

Comment: E_ERROR: I added json_last_error() to the debug.  Thank you for that.

Comment: how did you solve the issue?

Comment: @HasanTareque I don't know if StackOverflow pings people on update but I added what worked for my specific situation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really old question, but I had the same problem decoding JSON received from Amazon SNS. json_decode () was not working and json_last_error () was returning JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX.

After trying (and failing) with string replacement, I decided to disable "Include Original Headers" in Amazon SES (which sends the bounce notification to Amazon SNS). Suddenly everything worked fine.

[image: Setting In AWS SES]

For completeness, my PHP code to decode the string is as follows:

```
$decoded = json_decode (trim ($jsonFromAWS), true);
if (is_array ($decoded) && isset ($decoded['Message']) && !is_array ($decoded['Message']) && $decoded['Message'] !== '')
{
    $decoded['Message'] = json_decode (trim ($decoded['Message']), true);
}
```

Hope that helps anyone else bumping into this question!